# Set different htpasswd for different pages in site

Tags: .htaccess, .htpasswd

I want to set different htpasswd for different pages in my website. How can i do that?

Set different htpasswd for different pages in site...
Like example.com/about and example.com/portfolio should have different passwords.

Comment: Are these pages all in the root? Or do they have their own directories?

Comment: yes in side test/one.html, test/two.html and i want different password for both these files can you please write code? Thanks,

Comment: If they are in different directories as you say, then just create a `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd` file in the retrospective directories and add the authentication code into the `.htaccess` file and the username and password into the `.htpasswd` file. I will not write this for you. This is a security measure you're adding, do this yourself. You can use this [Generator](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/) if you need help with the password and username

Answer (score 1):

If each page has its own directory, then you can just create a `.htaccess` page for each one.

However, if they're all on the root, then you might be able to achieve this using an `if directive`

So for example:

```
<if "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'example.com/about'">
    ....
</if>
```

Then place your authentication code inside the `if directive`. You could do this for each directory you want to use a different password on.

Comment: hi @Lag its not working, i want to do something like if about text is in url then this code. So if request_uri like %about%. Do you know code or any link?

Comment: just change it to `<if "%{REQUEST_URI} == 'about'">`

Comment: hi @lag
`<If "%{REQUEST_URI} == '/sulu-onepager/web/first-page'">`
  `AuthUserFile /var/www/html/sulu-onepager/passwords/.htpasswd_1`
  `Require valid-user`
`</If>`
`<ElseIf "%{REQUEST_URI} == '/sulu-onepager/web/second-page'">`
  `AuthUserFile /var/www/html/sulu-onepager/passwords/.htpasswd_2`
  `Require valid-user`
`</ElseIf>`
`<Else>`
  `AuthUserFile /var/www/html/sulu-onepager/passwords/.htpasswd_1`
  `Require valid-user`
`</Else>` 
`elseif part not working not working i don't know whats wrong`

Comment: can you post that as an edit to your question please, very difficult to read and understand as a comment.